# Case study about Moya + Realm + ObjectMapper used together

Tags: ios, realm, objectmapper, moya

Recently i have been using these tree technologies combined together for a project:

- [Realm](https://realm.io/) for database
- [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) as network layer
- [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) for JSON object mapping

So i decided to write down a little case study with my considerations. 
https://github.com/matteogazzato/case-study-Moya-Realm-ObjectMapper

Maybe it can be useful or just a starting point of discussion about those arguments.
As i wrote in conclusions, feel free to comment/share/integrate/ask.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question, but rather is an announcement of a blog post; as such it is off-topic. Please see [ask] for more info.